# How to use z3 with C++ in Clion IDE?

Tags: c++, z3, clion

I referenc the head file `z3++.h` in my C++ program, but the program cannot identify it. I installed the z3 in my system. Do I need to configure Clion? How?

Comment: You need to "configure" you project `CMakeLists.txt` file (or `Makefile` if you use that). What you need to do is to tell where the file is installed, if it's not in a standard location.

Comment: Thanks! I figure it out. The format is : target_include_directories(project_Name PRIVATE[or public]  absolute_path)